# returning enum as char doesn't actually return the value of that enum

Tags: c, enums, return-value, c89, ansi-c

I have an enum:

```c
enum asm_adressing_types{instant = 0, direct = 1, relative = 2, instant_register = 3};
```

and I am returning values of the enum using the following function:

```c
char addressing_type(char *operand)
{
    switch (*operand)
    {
        case DIRECT_REGISTER_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL:
            return (char)(instant_register); /*<- This line get executed. (checked via debugger)*/
         break;
        case INSTANT_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL:
            return (char)(instant);
         break;
         case RELATIVE_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL:
            if(!is_register(operand))
                return (char)(direct);
            return (char)(relative);
         break;
        default:
          return (char)(direct);
    }
}
```

When I am trying to return `3` (`instant_register`) The value that is practically returned is `1`:

```c
if((commands + i)->operands.first_free_index >= 1 && (temp.command_byte_form.desttype = addressing_type(get_item_at_index((commands + i)->operands, 0)) == instant_register))
/*value of temp.command_byte_form.desttype after this line of code is 1 (checked via debugger)*/
```

Why that is? And how can I make the function return the actual value of the enum?

edit: : `desttype` is a 2 bit unsigned int bitfield

Comment: Why not change the function signature to `asm_adressing_types addressing_type(char *operand)`?

Comment: @Matthieu is not allowed via C89 standard

Comment: All your casts are redundant: remove the clutter.

Comment: Maybe `i` is 1 larger than the maximum index of the `commands` object, making `commands + i` UB?

Comment: @pmg in this case, ```i``` is 0. what is UB?

Comment: UB=Undefined Behaviour... and `0` is fine :)

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: this example might be slightly misleading. I am presuming you wanted to say that that `0x01000000 != 0x01`? `(char)0x00000001` should be `1` regardless of endianness.

Comment: I forgot to mention: desttype is a 2  bit unsigned int bitfield. does that may be the probalam?

Comment: @Groo that was the intent.

Comment: @avivgood2 you should post a MRE instead of describing parts of your code and forgetting things

Comment: If this is real code:  `temp.command_byte_form.desttype = addressing_type(get_item_at_index((commands + i)->operands, 0)) == instant_register`   then /facedesk  (the result of `==` operator can only ever be `0` or `1` so this code can only assign `0` or `1` to `.desttype`)

Comment: As M.M wrote, you're missing parentheses around `desttype = addresing_type(...)` in `desttype = addressing_type(...) == instant_register`, otherwise this gets evaluated as `desttype = (addressing_type(...) == instant_register)`. This often happens when you're making unecessary complex expression, however [enabling compiler warnings usually helps and saves a lot of time](https://godbolt.org/z/jnxTrc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not caused by the return value, the castings or the enumeration constants of `asm_adressing_types`, which do work perfectly.

It has to be caused by a match failure in the `switch` condition inside of the `addressing_type` function.

The pointer parameter `operand` is high-probably pointing to a value which does not match to the value of the `DIRECT_REGISTER_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL` ,`INSTANT_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL` and optionally also not the `RELATIVE_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL` symbols at the first, second and third case.

Thus the result is printing `1`, the value of the `direct` enumeration constant, which is returned at the third (when `is_register(operand)` returned `0`) or default `case`.

Here is the proof that it works properly, when f.e. `DIRECT_REGISTER_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL` matches `*operand`:

[Online](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qgA%2BhOSkAzpnbICeOpUy10AYVSsArgFtag1egAyeWpgByegEaZiIAMwBWUgAdU0wktqad%2Bwe6einSm5la6tvbOMnKYCt4MBMzEBL56Bpwx8sG0ickEoZY2do4u0kkpaf6Z5fmF4ZGlAJQyqNrEyBwA5ACkAEwOZsg6WADUPQ7q5fioAHQIE9g9AAwAgiurqnqjzNK6YszoxJjSnqJiBACerifjAOwAQqNmtfTjDgAio8uko/jHCneX0yo2OwkUADdMEDRn1fi8kvQxMdgHhynYYQ57h8Jk8NltdKNpJcIlppPcnh8AJIAJWw6gAKmI6QBxKkMBnYGliVYfOkMBhUiwssQc1Y0pkMACaAFkHgB5YwwsBdVYq35CsUWJm8/mC4WihniyWyhVKiZfFUPdWjOnGVYMqkANWwPL52AFQpFYolotNiuVXXUKuxuI2G2QCGSO3QRxOZ2AF2u0IgkejACpUDdiCJ0E0w2sNmYCKNdMwzKMIBDUHg8%2BHHhtRk3RmniDtA2reg4Ho3m63RunXDD%2BgA2ZgF1bN0auYjFqgQfp9fpOdCL36HOOnMyJq43CCuJr57v1nGFtb9jfHLfnXcp/uZ7O5/OFhtrKfSADuhEjlYfdifvZNj0r6TlOfa7NC1J0oyzLYGyHJcm6epeoaxp%2BnKiogIBYFTscBDtLQlatk0EAIiIBDIpgqLosQR5PAA9OmEzqAAtKMDIIGioysGY0LAJgJaYAAHnE2gEJg6CzERCBxAA1hJowQngzB/Jg1jaMA/G0em9HYThTbWMczCyRO%2BkthBoyaka2pIR6%2BrekavrShhxhYW%2BZnNnhBHSckJFkfQdF6fphmYMZpn6Swsi2tg9qOi6tmegaPomi5bmgR5zxUJWnBNBleU4fR9FEnguiuDxVB4CwOSjDQbYEDJRLGdCqBZfV0LCdmJWqAQsxBRlXnEIRqZRrRED/HEBCBe5/UCd5w2%2BRAYLMJCmBTelHkhWFx7TWBWBUMw2isAQaX5QNQ3EWNeAApN4UZZtJnbetwGnusdwvV0LSsCAXROF0pAGF0yx/ag33qESbQdNC/QOJwf3HYDH0tLJjh9LMAAcywOHcyycBj3CcM4fScCOQjfdwf0A0DpAg10f3SCAPzw0DLRwLAMCICgqClXg7BkBQqZc64PMlMgwAAJxwhVR12PTEDWN9VPWGYySXN9sOkGgui6N18q0KwqsI6QWBlqI7AK3943xFC9OG8Jonieb5D0HIjs8YZKuaFgatw7Oujey0ND0EwbAcDw/CCMIoggBIYhSG79OwLQzDayg0hOD8UL2F0YucMzLRZjkNssQA6mwrCjCXwkEDmFfFzc6DkZVte0KgLHaLQ2iyOgLEQskynWOwzet64yTdTJsjSHTsTxMoEBGFUGSkEY9TFPYmSBF4dALwEHib7QK8RCUNTTzkeSVFo6SCLI2QJBUBS8Q0R8yHf281HfB%2BNDlrTtJ0XCfd9v1/qOxpkJNGI4WIjm4KMYAyBkCjDFrMPolZcCEBIOMAYIJNDc15ugmGuV1Bw3NoeUgyN06ky6OTUgfsyGU2Bt9OmDNSBMw%2BqQVmHM2gEFcGJcglBNZC15oYfARA16kEDowFgZsw4fhzK4f25DAG0Opt9aGnBRhfnqqMUB4DIHQNgfAxBhCEbEJkocEoEAkZcGWD8L6FC/rUJ%2BIommDDGZEIsc4WYOMnBODuETJwYCHDcDhDYhwFNgH0KYUQ1h7M2EQCQHw4WfNeGCwSSgYYIhgC5ysaInm4liCy3lobJWSdiAG3VprbW9Bdb60dsbdJZtDaWxWjbKmdtkBiW6FTYsLtDZuxzCUz23R1bVxKnIsRwdJG8AEEE9J0dJBCDwNYBO5jqauELt9EuZch5tw7l3HufdmAD2hCXFuLER7HHoOPE4U8b6z3nhfaoS81AfyfhvHIr83C7xyM8kR18Jq33yO835M9cjvwfqvK%2BL97mL1qCkb5f9v6Q3hTYhRYSuhaIgVAtJohRi5w8R45BQi0EqN%2BFg/hGJoZ9HwYYvOJDHAOFmA4RlTLmXMvIZQ%2BxQDDZOJkIw5hLNolIA4VwggPCBbYJKHCCSqCRFjIkaHXg0jmCyK6LDf%2BP1QlcuUQMJB6iECaLARilskdgA4uWHiqmfKWgmKwPYZZNj2UgBoai5xESjFuNRrjZYPiRyYx8Q4ZYTgxbkJCZyqm3LLXkL6BqsN4SI2Z08MobgQA%3D)

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum asm_adressing_types { instant = 0, direct = 1, relative = 2, instant_register = 3 }; 
enum symbols { DIRECT_REGISTER_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL = 'A', INSTANT_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL = 'B', RELATIVE_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL = 'C' };

char addressing_type (char *operand);

int main (void)
{
    char a = 'A';
    char *p = &a;
    printf("%d", addressing_type(p));
}

char addressing_type (char *operand)
{
    switch (*operand)
    {
        case DIRECT_REGISTER_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL:
            return (char)(instant_register); /*<- This line get executed. (checked via debugger)*/
            break;
        case INSTANT_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL:
            return (char)(instant);
            break;
        case RELATIVE_ADRESSING_START_SYMBOL:
            if (1)                           // simplification for the sake of the experiment.
                return (char)(direct);
            return (char)(relative);
            break;
        default:
            return (char)(direct);
            break;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

Note that the casting and the surrounding parentheses for the enumerations constants is redundant. You can just use:

```
return instant_register;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must provide more information about your code; However the return value of switch case is OK. Please avoid from complicated conditions. Use `addressing_type` in a separate line before condition and see the result.

Run just this code and you can see the result is 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>
enum asm_adressing_types{instant = 0, direct = 1, relative = 2, instant_register = 3}; 

char addressing_type(char *operand)
{
    switch (*operand)
    {
        case 1:
            return (char)(instant_register); /*<- This line get executed. (checked via debugger)*/
         break;
         default:
            return (char)(direct);
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    char a[12] = {1};
    char c = addressing_type(a);
    printf("Hello World %d", c);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Likely, your mistake is in your condition.